# Template format error: YAML not well-formed Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

```
BucketPolicy:
Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
DeletionPolicy: Retain
Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2008-10-17
      Id: PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent
      Statement:
        - Sid: AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
          Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::travissalmonwebsite/*'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'AWS:SourceArn': 'arn:aws:cloudfront::224062589507:distribution/EY5YTW9GQAJ75'
        - Sid: PublicGetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::travissalmonwebsite/*'
```

When I attempt to upload my yaml file to import my existing resources, I get an error stating my 'Statement' and 'Id' lines are not well formed. I tried different indentations. Not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please use YAML validator.

```yaml
Resources:
  MyWebsite:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: travissalmonwebsite-mehmet

  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2008-10-17'
        Id: PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent
        Statement:
        - Sid: AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
          Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::travissalmonwebsite-mehmet/*'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'AWS:SourceArn': 'arn:aws:cloudfront::224062589507:distribution/EY5YTW9GQAJ75'
        - Sid: PublicGetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::travissalmonwebsite-mehmet/*'
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I did, it just gives me the line and column # the error is occurring on (Line 32, column 20)

Comment: Please give more details about your error, I updated my answer with working solution.

Comment: I ended up restarting the project. I found out about the yaml lint website to help me understand whats wrong with my format. Thank you for your assistance. I actually came across a new error if you dont mind checking it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75657851/e2507-iam-policy-key-version-doesnt-exist