# E2507 IAM Policy key version doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

```
Unknown field version (Service: Amazon S3;       
Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy;   
Request ID: VKA1M3MNY37B2DGN; S3 Extended        
Request ID: UItdX5yp9vy6KB19HQVjBdkW1fyGh2EvZ+47 
Y1KcQ03WExKAqRVJivrw+4cQns6OXo7ax8lwO2Y=; Proxy:                                                                                                                                                         null)
```

```
BucketPolicy:
Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
Properties:
  PolicyDocument:
    Id: MyPolicy
    version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObject
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: "s3:GetObject"
        Resource: !Join
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
            - !Ref MyWebsite
            - /*
  Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite
```

I receive the error message above when I deploy my bucket policy.

When I use the yaml lint site it says format is fine but when I use the CLI `sam validate --lint` command I get this message:

> E2507 IAM Policy key version doesn't exist.

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Version`, not `version`. CloudFormation is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: I changed this and I am still receiving the same error code

Comment: @TravisSalmon This means your real code is different then in the question. In that case one one can help you sadly.